# which rails version should i use rails 6.1.3.2 or rails 6.1.4 (which is the latest one)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6.1

i am creating the rails application from scrath it was in 6.1.3.2, but now automatically all the related modules (activesupport activerecord) are now updated to the 6.1.4 from 6.1.3.2. is it good to go with 6.1.4 ?, if No , how can i get back to the 6.1.3.2 ?

Comment: The version of any gem (including rails) can be specified in your app's `Gemfile`. See [the bundler docs](https://bundler.io/gemfile.html) for information. You can be as specific or lax in specifying the version as you want. The jump from `6.1.3.2` to `6.1.4` is pretty minor (especially if you are just starting an app), but if you really want to go back set the version to `~>6.1.3.2` and re-run `bundle install`.

Comment: @rmlockerd thanks for the quick response
 but  my gemfile already consists of 6.1.3.2 but in lockfile it is 6.1.4 that's the reason i asked the question

Comment: How exactly does the `rails` line in your `Gemfile` look like?

Comment: @spickermann gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.3'

Comment: If a version has only numbers you can assume that it is stable. An unstable version might look like this: `6.1.0.rc2` where (`rc2` stands for release candidate 2) or `6.0.0.beta1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.3'
```

in your `Gemfile` means that `bundler` is allowed to update patch level releases but not to the next minor release (read about [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/)) which is basically the same as `>= 6.1.3` but `< 6.2`.

This is usually called pessimistic version constraint because it allows bundler to install patch level releases which are usually bug fixes. But bundler cannot update to the next minor release which might include changes to the API and might break your code.

Updating minor and especially major versions you will certainly have to change your code a bit and it is advised to have good tests when planning a major update.

If you really want to pin Rails to a specific version (what I would not recommend) then you can use

```
gem 'rails', '6.1.3.2'
```

in your `Gemfile`,

That all said: It is actually a good thing to install updates are soon as they are available because they fix bugs and might improve the performance. Running several versions behind has huge disadvantages: It is harder to find developers willing to work with older versions. It is harder to get help or to find documentation. And gems might not be available for older versions.

My recommendation is: Always keep your dependencies (not only Rails) up-to-date. When there is a new version that doesn't work with your codebase then stop implementing new features and adapt your codebase to the new version first.

Comment: Note that minor releases might add functionality, but should be backwards compatible. Meaning that an upgrade to the next minor release should not break your current code. In practice not all gems and even Ruby itself don't always follow this rule. Most of the time it is safe to upgrade to the next minor release, but before you do make sure you have read the release notes. In (semantic versioning) theory only major release are allowed to break code.

Answer (score 1):

It's always recommenced to use the latest stable version of rails and other gems. As you mention `6.1.4` is the latest version atm. So don't be afraid of this change. It's good to update your gems from time to time anyway.

Comment: is that a stable one?

Comment: @PrateekVyas yes, https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2021/6/24/Rails-6-1-4-has-been-released/